# Compiling only a specific driver from backports?

Tags: linux, compilation, linux-kernel, driver

I'm currently trying to learn a bit about how txpower is set within the Linux ath9k wireless driver to enable the output amp on my wireless adaptor.

I've been editing the code for ath9k from here: https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/stable/v4.4.2/

On my Raspberry Pi, this is a 15+ minute compile process.

Is anybody able to tell me if it's possible to just compile the ath9k driver rather than the whole lot?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was fairly simple:

`make defconfig-ath9k`

`make`

Hope this helps somebody!